# Get keyboard shortcut entered in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a Revit plug in that gets the command that a user activated from the ribbon bar.  I now need to do the same when the user types a shortcut sequence.  What event should I be using to intercept this?

Answer (score 0):

don't believe that will be possible using Revit API, but you may track the keys events for the shortcut you need...

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Any idea if AutoCAD API has this ability?

Comment: on AutoCAD you can track the command that was executed. But the same key tracking should work

try CommandStarted event